# WCF username authentication not working

Tags: wcf-binding, wcf-configuration, wcf-authentication

I'm new to WCF service. I wanted to create a WCF service with **basichttpbinding** to create a custom authentication mechanism before giving access to my WCF service. I have used 
**security mode = Transport** and **clientcredentialtype = basic**. I have written a custom validator function for validating my username and password.

validator function

```
namespace CustomValidator

 {
  public class MyCustomValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator

   {
      public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
     {
         // This isn't secure, though!
        if ((userName != "check") || (password != "check"))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Validation Failed!");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my service config file

```
  < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" propagateActivity="true"></endToEndTracing>
    </diagnostics>


    <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
       <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
       <!--  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />-->
       </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"    name="BasicHttpEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="IService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"   contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <serviceCredentials>

                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CustomValidator.MyCustomValidator, App_Code" />

                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />

        </authentication>

    </security>
</system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

So the problem here is that whenever I run my service, I get a login dialog were I enter username and password(my validator expects both username and password to be same), I'm not getting my service details page, which used to come up in normal case (without authentication mechanism). I don't know what I'm missing, I do feel like its all in configurations which matters in my case but still I can't find out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have Created and Shared a Demo Project for Username Password Authentication.Its Working Fine.
Pls Check

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FE322C74D6AA4D1%21169

You can use SelfCert,given inside,to Create a Certificate with name **TrustedPeople** , Store Location **LocalMachine**